# Keep OperationContext in task parallel library

Tags: .net, wcf, task-parallel-library, operationcontext

we have somewhere in a deep abstraction assembly a WCF behavior that reads data from the OperationContext.Current, when this code is executed from within a Task, the OperationContext.Current is empty, is it possible to solve this inside the abstraction assembly or will we need to add some code to all consumers of this assembly?

Comment: Who starts the `Task`? The consumer? Is any code from the abstraction assembly executed before starting the `Task`?

Comment: no, that is the problem, the consumer starts the tasks :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only way is to add something to the CallContext, just like the current Principal is stored...

Answer (score 3):

Was facing a similar issue. Was calling a service through Task.
The following code snippet worked out. The `OperationContext.Current` was explicitly set by casting the `state` variable being provided by `Task` before the call to service is done.

```
Task<int> taskContactsCount = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>((state) =>
        {
            int count = 0;
            try
            {
                OperationContext.Current = (OperationContext)state;
                TestServiceClient testServiceProxy = new TestServiceClient();
                var count = testServiceProxy.GetCount();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return contactsCount;
        }, OperationContext.Current);
```

Answer (score 2):

At the point where you create your [`Task` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), you should use a closure, like so:

```
// The operation context.
OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // Do something with context here, it will be valid for
    // the life of the operation.
};
```

You can also call the [overload of `StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456) which takes a `state` parameter and pass the [`OperationContext` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) in, casting and using it when needed in the `Task`, like so:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(s => {
    // s is an object, so need to cast here.
    var oc = (OperationContext) c;

    // Work with the OperationContext.
},
// Note, this is passed to the delegate through the 's' parameter.
OperationContext.Current);
```

Note that in both cases, the `OperationContext` will only be good for the life of the operation.  The completion of the operation should be dependent on the completion of the `Task`.

If you are launching a `Task` that will run *after* the operation completes, then you should copy the values you need from the `OperationContext` into another structure and pass *those* into your `Task` for processing.

Comment: yes that I know, but the problem is cannot force the consumer code to not just start a Task and do stuff :)

Comment: @TimMahy Then it seems you have to build the context into your abstractions, passing it around where you need it.